# Append timers using jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have created a timer using jQuery and javascript. I have appended the timer in a page. Each timer has start, stop and reset button. The problem is that when i click on the second, third, fourth.......... etc timer, only the first timer is working. No other timer is working for me.Below is my code. Can anyone please help me.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            window.onload=function(){document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "00" + ":" +"00" + ":" + "00";}
        </script>

        <div class="timers" id="act">
            <div id="time"></div>
            <div class="timer_controls">
                <input class="btnStart" id="start" type="button" value="Start" onclick="timer()" />
                <input class="btnreset" id="reset" type="button" value="Reset" onclick="reset()" />
                <input class="btnStop" id="stop" type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stopper()" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <input id="appends" type="button" value="append" />
        <div class="container"></div>

        <style type="text/css">
            #time{
                font-size:50pt;
            }
            .container{
                float:left;
                width:100%;
                height:1000px;
            }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            i = 0;
            var w;

            function timer() {
                if (i > 3599) {
                    var H = Math.floor(i / 3600);
                }
                else {
                    var H = 0;
                }

                var M = i - (H * 3600)

                if (M > 59) {
                    M = Math.floor(M / 60)
                }
                else {
                    M = 0
                }

                var S = i - (M * 60)
                if (S > 3599) {
                    S = Math.floor(M / 3600)
                }

                if (H < 10) {
                    H = "0" + H;
                }
                if (M < 10) {
                    M = "0" + M;
                }
                if (S < 10) {
                    S = "0" + S;
                }

                document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = H + ":" + M + ":" + S;
                w=setTimeout('timer()', 1000);
                i++;
            }

            function stopper(){
                clearTimeout(w);
            }

            function reset() {
                i=0;
                document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "00" + ":" +"00" + ":" + "00";
                clearTimeout(w);
            }

            $("#appends").click(function() {
                var index = $('.timers').length;
                clearTimeout(w);
                var timing=$('.timers').html();
                $('.container').append('<div class="timers" id="act_'+(index+1)+'">'+timing+'<input          class="btnStart" id="start'+(index+1)+'" type="button" value="Start" onclick="timer()" />'+'</div>');
            });
        </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It might be beneficial if you try and build up a working example of your code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).  I did try and do it for you but couldn't get it to run.  In that way we'll be far better suited and able to help you.

Comment: That's because you are using `id` to target the timer instead of `class`. Hence only the first element with `id=time` is targeted no matter which button you click. Try making a JavaScript class using prototypes. That way you can create a reusable timer component.

Comment: Easy way to show your code is to use http://jsfiddle.net or http://plnkr.co/

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable replies. I have put my code in jsfiddle.net. This is the link http://jsfiddle.net/toyson88/yhqR9/15/ . When I put this code in the fiddle the timer itself is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one uniqe id per HTML element on page. Every time you append new timer they all have similar Id's. So you need to change some logic of your script